# How to get translated text pronunciation in english letters using Google Cloud Translate?

Tags: translation, google-translate, translate, google-cloud-transcoder

How to get translated text pronunciation in English letters using Google Cloud Translate?

For example, cloud translate API can give "नमस्ते" when trying to translate from the English word "Hello". But, I also want "namaste" which is usually displayed on the Google translate website.

Is there any way I can get it? I am not able to find it even in paid libraries.

Answer (score 2):

It is called `transliteration` (translating text pronunciation into another language) and Google Cloud Translate API does not support this feature yet.

However, there is a feature request [filed](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/35900102) for the same. You can vote for this feature by clicking the "+1" and "STAR" mark to receive updates on it or  you can also create a feature request thread in Google’s [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).