# Transliteration from a source language to Roman (English) script

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, google-api, artificial-intelligence, transliteration

We need the Romanization feature badly. Can someone please help? We want to transliterate (**not translate**) from Hindi (Devanagiri script) language to English (Roman script) language.

**Input**
`romanize_text('अंतिम लक्ष्य क्या है')`

**Expected Output**
`'antim lakshya kya hai'`

As per the [Google Romanize text docs](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/romanize-text#romanize_text), I wrote the following Python code to transliterate from some language script to Roman script.

```py
# Authenticate using credentials.
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "translate.json"

PROJECT_ID = "project-id"
LOCATION = "global"

# Imports the Google Cloud Translation library
from google.cloud import translate_v3

# Transliteration.
def romanize_text(text, src_lang="hi", tgt_lang="en"):

    client = translate_v3.TranslationServiceClient()
    parent = f"projects/{PROJECT_ID}/locations/{LOCATION}"

    response = client.romanize_text(
        request={
            "parent": parent,
            "contents": [text],
            "source_language_code": src_lang,
            "target_language_code": tgt_lang,
        }
    )

    # Display the romanized for each input text provided
    for romanization in response.romanizations:
        print(f"Romanized text: {romanization.romanized_text}")

romanize_text('अंतिम लक्ष्य क्या है')
```

Running the above code, gives the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'TranslationServiceClient' object has no attribute 'romanize_text'
```

Also, in the [Google's API reference of romanizeText](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects/romanizeText), the right-hand side API Explorer is broken. Whereas, if you select any other method from the left-hand side - its API Explorer works correctly.

We need the Romanization feature badly: so either a solution to the aforementioned problem, or an alternative non-Google solution for romanization would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving the error when you call `client.romanize_text` in your function because there is no `romanize_text` function in the [source code](https://github.com/googleapis/python-translate/blob/main/google/cloud/translate_v3/services/translation_service/client.py) for the client.

The [transliteration documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/translating-text-v3#transliteration) for "advanced translating text v3" says that:

> Transliteration is a configuration setting in the `translateText` method. When you enable transliteration, you translate romanized text (Latin script) directly to a target language.

However, you want to translate from a specified language to romanized text so this feature doesn't seem to be available (yet) via the Google Cloud Translate API. This observation is substantiated/alluded to in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74571174/20087266) to a question similar to yours.

It seems like the PyPI package [ai4bharat-transliteration](https://pypi.org/project/ai4bharat-transliteration/) by the researchers at [AI4Bharat](https://ai4bharat.org) is a viable non-Google alternative for transliteration from Hindi to romanized text.

Comment: I tried non-Google AIs like `polyglot` and `indic-transliteration` which didn't work well. `AI4Bharat` is better than those two. **Thanks Kyle**.   

For Google's `romanize_text` API not working, I've reported them at 2 places:  
1. [Google API groups](https://groups.google.com/g/google-apis-discovery/c/F7DV4kWikNE)  
2. [Github Issue](https://github.com/googleapis/python-translate/issues/490)  

Do you agree that no other library can beat Google's AI transliteration capability? I think so, that is why I've reported them at both the places in hope that they'll consider my issue.

Comment: @RajdeepPal The modern transformer encoder-decoder models which are used for these types of conversion tasks require expertise to design, and substantial amounts of data and compute power to train. Google has both; hence, their library works so well in a variety of tasks. Usually only dedicated libraries which focus on a niche (like AI4Bharat's focus on only Indic languages) will match or exceed Google's generalised yet powerful capability. Feedback always helps guide development focus, so hopefully they'll take yours on-board and add the feature.